# Change the number of figures or tables in the appendix of my thesis in latex

Tags: tables, floats

I am working on my thesis in Latex with "book" documentclass. There are a couple of chapters in the thesis with several tables or figures. When I put all those tables or figures after the Appendix, the numbers of them changed, e.g. from "3.1" (First table in Chapter 3) to "A1".
I was wondering if someone could help me keep the format of numbers of tables or figures as "3.1", "3.2", etc. By the way, I used "\appendix" for the appendix section. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `figure`s and `table` assume a `<chapter>.<float>` numbering scheme under [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co). More formally,

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
```

(with some conditional that is not important here). And, with an issue of `\appendix`, `\thechapter` is updated to `\Alph{chapter}`. For your purposes it seems to suffice to hard-code `\thechapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}

\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{3}%
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The assumption is, of course, that you don't have any `figure`s or `table`s in Chapter 3, otherwise this would definitely confuse the reader. Moreover, if you are using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), such redefinitions could cause problems with hyperlinking if the figure number is not unique.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it seems that this didn't work when I put the code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it seems that this didn't work when I put the code "\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}' and '\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}} ' at the top of the tables. I am not sure if I made myself clear. I was wondering if there is a way that I could move the tables within Chapter 3 to the end of my thesis (after the appendix) but keep the numbers as 3.1, 3.2, etc. Thanks again!

Comment: @lei: Yes. Move all the tables to your appendix where you want them and immediately before them, add `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{3}` as I mention towards the end of my answer. The original definitions of `\thefigure` and `\thetable` was just given for reference.

Comment: Thanks! It worked this time. One more thing is that how can I restart the number of tables for each chapter, such as 3.1, 3.2 then 4.1, 4.2? Now it comes with 3.1,3.2, but 4.3, 4.4.....

Comment: I figured it out. It restarted the number of tables for each chapter by adding setcounter{table}{0}. Thank you for your help!